# href is not working after click

Tags: javascript, html, angular

i reused component from another team and everything looks fine.
It is some "login experience" so we have some icon and after click we can see links. But when i hover over links, i am able to see redirect url ("in left bottom corner"), however when i click on them, nothing happens. When i rightclick and press open in new tab, it works.

So basically i think something is preventing click() event. As i could not find the rootcause, i tried to add there some custom click event, which will take "link" from href attribute and will do

```
window.location.href
```

And then something strange happened. I tried to loop through links which specific  classes and nothing happened. Selector works because i can see HTML collection when i do :

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('link'));
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('link').length);
```

it retrieves HTMLCollection and i can see elements. But second log returns '0'. So i am not able in this point manipulate this link.

In console when I expanded HTMLCollection it has some "i" mark that says Value was calculated/evaluated just now.
But when i do same length check right in chrome console it returns correct value.

It looks like DOM is manipulated and rendered after my code is called.

Has anybody faced issue like this, please?

Thanks,

But when i do console.log

## UPDATE #1

```
stop(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName !== 'A') {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

This is event that is making some stop. But i dont think this is my case because HTML code is exactly the same as component which is working. I just added class to override it

Comment: Can you post the code so we can see it? Makes it a lot easier.

Comment: Check you browser console to see if there are any errors before or after you click.

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem. Perhaps a div overlaying the links. Click F12 and seem what highlights when you hover the links

Comment: There are no errors in console

Comment: @mplungjan It is not overlaying, i tried this as first "wannabe" solution :) i can see link when i hover over <a> element, actually i think i wouldnt be able to see link in the left bottom corner

Comment: Martin Fric : Is your href bound by any other event handler which has any events like preventDefault or stopPropagation in it?

Comment: I found one. I will update the question

Comment: @SumodhNair U can see code in update

Comment: @MartinFric can you attach a debugger to that "stop" method and see if any bubbling is taking place?

Comment: @SumodhNair you are right... It is going to this condition :/

Comment: @MartinFric just update your code on the basis of your requirement then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177722/discussion-between-martin-fric-and-sumodh-nair).